# Search for files after a relative date using Windows search

Tags: windows, windows-search, date-modified

I am looking for a way to save a search that includes a relative date.  Specifically I am looking for a way to save a search that matches files that have a modification date that is **7 days ago**.

I have read the [Windows Search Advanced Query Syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx) document and I am not seeing a way to say 7 days ago.

The [numbers and ranges](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/desktopsearch/technicalresources/advquery.mspx#E1E) section does mention that relative dates are possible.  The problem is that the relative dates described there do not fit the criteria I need.  The **lastweek** almost looks like what I want except if I run a query like `after:lastweek` on a Monday it will only show my file that have been modified since Sunday at 12:00.  The lastweek/lastmonth seem to relative to the start of the week/month which is not what I need.

> Multi-word relative dates: week, next
>   month, last week, past month, or
>   coming year. The values can also be
>   entered contracted, as follows:
>   thisweek, nextmonth, lastweek,
>   pastmonth, comingyear.

One nice thing about saved searches is that they are stored as an XML document and the file format is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892885(VS.85).aspx).  I am not seeing how to form a correct value for a datetime.  If I was able to understand this format, I suspect I could use a text editor and created a saved search that does what I want.

Fragment from the [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892885(VS.85).aspx#savedsearch_examples):

```
<conditions>
  <condition type="leafCondition" valuetype="System.StructuredQueryType.DateTime"
             property="System.DateModified" operator="imp" 
             value="R00UUUUUUUUZZXD-30NU" propertyType="wstr" />
</conditions>
```

To summarize I am looking for an answer to one or both of these questions

- How do I make a query for '7 days ago' using the standard syntax?
- How is the DateTime stored in a saved search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the first part of your question: `R00UUUUUUUUZZXD-30NU` tells Windows to search the last 30 days.  Changing 30 to 1 *(i.e., `R00UUUUUUUUZZXD-1NU`)* would make it search the last 24 hours.

In your case you are looking to set the value to `R00UUUUUUUUZZXD-7NU`.  Reference this [forum post.](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-file-management/153545-delete-content-tracking-searches-folder.html)

For the second part of your question perhaps start by looking at the [`System.DateModified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760685%28VS.85%29.aspx) documentation. The other type that's mentioned, `System.StructuredQueryType.DateTime`, I am unable to find documentation on.

**Update:**

I found this [gem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231387%28VS.85%29.aspx) that gets us closer to deciphering how to construct the relative `DateTime` values.  Consider this quote:

> For example, Structured Query supports
>   relative date/time expressions, which
>   remain unresolved until they are
>   applied to some reference time. In a
>   leaf node with semantic type
>   System.StructuredQueryType.DateTime,
>   the value can be either a VT_FILETIME
>   or a VT_LPWSTR. VT_FILETIME is an
>   absolute date/time so it is already
>   resolved. VT_LPWSTR is a string
>   representation of a relative date/time
>   expression. The specified reference
>   time should be a local time, but the
>   resolved times in the resulting query
>   expression will be in coordinated
>   universal time (UTC).

and finally [this forum posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment/thread/0feadd78-fe45-46c2-91f4-70599b30afd8)
 has another example of what the `DateTime` is stored.

The best I can tell it is a relative date/time format. I am still unable to find any hard documentation on it.

Comment: +1. Nice job digging up the meaning of "R00UUUUUUUUZZXD-30NU".

Answer (score 1):

Just write a script (PowerShell or Batch) that takes today's date, subtracts 7 days and executes a search based on the result. That way, you won't have to save the search, just run the script.

Comment: While I agree this is possible work around.  This really isn't the solution I am looking for.  Plus, somebody should know how the datetime value is structured.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample search file to recreate programmatically. I searched for video files in a specified folder, modified in the last 2 weeks ("datemodified: 3/17/2017..4/1/2017").

This gave me a .search-ms file full of things such as:

```
<condition type="leafCondition" property="System.DateModified" operator="imp" propertyType="stringarray" value="N00K2017K3K17UUUUUZZNNU; N00K2017K4K1UUUUUZZNNU" valuetype="System.StructuredQueryType.DateTime" localeName="en-US">
```

The key here being

> value="N00K**2017**K**3**K**17**UUUUUZZNNU; N00K**2017**K**4**K**1**UUUUUZZNNU"

You can notice the dates are plainly written, prepended by the letter K. N00 then K, then the year, and so on.

> N00`K[year]K[month]K[day]`UUUUUZZNNU

I wrote a simple console application to generate a search file with the specific dates of within the last 2 weeks, and set up Windows Task Scheduler to run it every day at midnight for my own purposes. I'm sure you could do the same.

I agree the workaround method is no substitute for being able to generate the search file. One thing people may not know is you can treat .search-ms files as folders, even going as far as to include them as a toolbar folder on your taskbar.